# Implement bash auto completion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, autocomplete

I created a script supposed to use python to autocomplete Python commands. The full code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/gndu91/d09f7bb42956eea08a0f4a6b3d6d5b93), however, I can give you an example. For instance, let's consider:

- `command`, the command I want to give completion to (it does not have to actually exist).
- `script.py`, the auto completion script.

```py
import os, shlex


def complete(current_word, full_line):
    split = shlex.split(full_line)
    prefixes = ("test", "test-中文", 'test-한글')
    items = list(i + "-level-" + current_word for i in prefixes)
    word = "" if len(split) - 1 < int(current_word) else split[int(current_word)]
    return list(i for i in items if i.startswith(word))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.sys.stdout.write(" ".join(complete(
            *os.sys.argv.__getitem__(slice(2, None)))))
    os.sys.stdout.flush()
```

The following script can be executed directly into the shell, or added in the .bashrc to keep the changes persistent.

```bsh
__complete_command() {
    COMPREPLY=($(python3 script.py complete $COMP_CWORD "${COMP_LINE}"));
};
complete -F __complete_command command
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.8.
If you want, you can type the following in a new console

```bsh
cd $(mktemp -d)
__complete_command() {
    COMPREPLY=($(python3 script.py complete $COMP_CWORD "${COMP_LINE}"));
};
complete -F __complete_command command
echo '
import os, shlex


def complete(current_word, full_line):
    split = shlex.split(full_line)
    prefixes = ("test", "test-中文", "test-한글")
    items = list(i + "-level-" + current_word for i in prefixes)
    word = "" if len(split) - 1 < int(current_word) else split[int(current_word)]
    return list(i for i in items if i.startswith(word))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.sys.stdout.write(" ".join(complete(
            *os.sys.argv.__getitem__(slice(2, None)))))
    os.sys.stdout.flush()' > script.py
```

Is it the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: The documentation for `complete` is in the Bash man page, under "Builtin Commands".  On some systems there's a separate `bash-builtins` man page for convenience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Splitting words

The Python script splits the shell command's full line to words using `shlex`.
I see a few issues with this:

1. I'm not sure this will split the line exactly the same way as the shell would. Looking at `help(shlex)`, I see *"A lexical analyzer class for simple shell-like syntaxes"*, and I find that not very reassuring.
2. I think command line completion should be blazingly fast, so I look suspiciously at anything that needs to be `import`-ed, such as `shlex`.
3. Looking at the **Programmable Completion** section in `man bash`, it seems that Bash populates the `COMP_WORDS` array with the result of the split.

Therefore, it would be good to pass `COMP_WORDS` to the Python script,
which would eliminate all the above concerns.

One way to achieve this would be to call the Python script with:

```
python3 script.py complete "$COMP_CWORD" "${COMP_WORDS[@]}"
```

And then change the Python script accordingly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def complete(comp_cword, *comp_words):
    prefixes = ("test", "test-中文", "test-한글")
    word = comp_words[int(comp_cword)]
    items = (prefix + "-level-" + comp_cword for prefix in prefixes)
    return (item for item in items if item.startswith(word))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.stdout.write(" ".join(complete(*sys.argv[2:])))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

#### Avoid converting generators to list when not needed

No lists were needed in the original script, everything could have been just generator expressions.

#### Keep it simple

I don't understand why the script imports `os` and uses `os.sys` and nothing else in `os`.
You could just `import sys` instead.

I don't understand why `sys.argv.__getitem__(slice(2, None))` was used instead of the simple and natural `sys.argv[2:]`.

---

This line is complex, it takes attention to understand:

> ```
> word = "" if len(split) - 1 < int(current_word) else split[int(current_word)]
> ```

This is a lot easier to understand:

```
if len(split) - 1 < int(current_word):
    word = ""
else:
    word = split[int(current_word)]
```

Looking further, `word` is used only in a filter `.startswith(word)`.
That filter will match every string.
In which case, to maximize performance,
it would be best to not create `word`, and not do any filtering,
but return `items` directly:

```
if len(split) - 1 < int(current_word):
    return items
```

On even closer look,
I don't see how `COMP_CWORD` can ever be an index out of range.
So the check for bounds was unnecessary.
(Strictly speaking, an index out of bounds may be possible when splitting words with `shlex`, since that might not be identical to the shell's own word splitting. Even then, it would be a highly unlikely case, therefore a more Pythonic way to handle the situation would be using a `try-expect` for a `IndexError`.)

#### Use better names

The name `i` is really best reserved for loop counters.
(Even then, often you may find better names...)

In the suggested solution above I renamed the parameter names to match the shell variables they come from.
I find this reduces the cognitive burden when reading the documentation of the variables in `man bash`, and the implementation of the completion code in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `man bash` was the resource I was looking for (I could find the necessary explanations about the variables). Also, the reason I used __getitem__ was because my keyboard was broken and I was unable to type [.

Comment: The line `word = "" if len(split) - 1 < int(current_word) else split[int(current_word)]` was here because, for instance if I am at the beginning of a new word, the split list will only contain the completed words, but not the current word (because empty).

Answer (score 6):

```
list(i for i in items if i.startswith(word))
```

This is just a list comprehension with extra steps (and overhead). If you want a list as an end result, wrap the comprehension in `[]`, not `()`.

```
[i for i in items if i.startswith(word)]
```

You were using a generator expression to produce a generator, then forcing it by putting it into a list.

Then, the same change can be made to the definition of `items`. This will be more efficient, and looks cleaner anyway.

---

If you're only supporting newer versions of Python (3.7+), I think [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#rationale) would also neaten up `items`:

```
items = [f"{i}-level-{current_word}" for i in prefixes]
```

---

```
"" if len(split) - 1 < int(current_word) else split[int(current_word)]
```

I think the condition is complex/varied enough that it takes a couple looks to see the `else`. Personally, I'd wrap the condition in parenthesis:

```
"" if (len(split) - 1 < int(current_word)) else split[int(current_word)]
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of where to search for the 'complete' definition, because I even looked up COMP_LINE in the entire linux repository (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=COMP_LINE&type=Code), the coreutil one (I downloaded it and ran "grep -r . -e 'COMP_LINE'"), but nothing appears, I even tried xterm, gnome-terminal, but there is no trace of this function. I tried to use forkstat to get the process but nothing.

Comment: @NadirGhoul Couldn't tell you. Coincidently, I just used Linux for the first time today.

Comment: You have searched a lot of unrelated sources, but not the Bash sources. https://github.com/bminor/bash/search?q=COMP_LINE&unscoped_q=COMP_LINE

Comment: @tripleee Nope. I only started using the bash and Linux a little over a week ago like I said. I'm still becoming familiar with it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sys.stdout.write` + `flush` is a fancy `print` call... You could just write

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     print(*complete(*sys.argv[2:]), end='', flush=True)
```

instead.